# How come my NavigationLink won't work when clicked?

Tags: swift, xcode, view, swiftui, navigation

I am trying to make it so that when I click the icon, the "scoreView()" is opened. When I click it, nothing works right now. Here is the code:

```
HStack {
    Image(systemName: "arrow.counterclockwise")
                        
    NavigationLink(destination: scoreView(scoreTracker: $scoreTracker)) {
        Spacer()
        Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
    }
                    
}
```

Does it have something to do with the fact that I don't have a navigationView? I'm new to this and experimenting so I'm not very clear on it.

**EDIT:**
I have added a NavigationView, yet the NavigationLink covers half the screen, and when clicked, the view is only changed in that square.
[Before clicking the NavigationLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfbIZ.png)
[After clicking the NavigationLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svjfG.png)

HStack {
Image(systemName: "arrow.counterclockwise")

```
                NavigationView {
                    NavigationLink(destination: scoreView(scoreTracker: $scoreTracker)) {
                        Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Yes, a NavigationLink must be within a NavigationView in order to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it have something to do with the fact that I don't have a navigationView?

Yes. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink):

> Users click or tap a navigation link to present a view inside a [NavigationView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationview).

It will **only** work inside a `NavigationView`. If you're not using one, consider [`sheet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(ispresented:ondismiss:content:)) or [`fullScreenCover`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fullscreencover(ispresented:ondismiss:content:)) instead. Or, make your own overlay with a [`ZStack`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/zstack).

---

Example `NavigationView` usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView { /// directly inside `var body: some View`
            VStack { /// if you have multiple views, make sure to put them in a `VStack` or similar
                Text("Some text")
                                            /// `ScoreView` should be capitalized
                NavigationLink(destination: ScoreView(scoreTracker: $scoreTracker)) {
                    Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. However, my app is doing something odd after I add the NavigationView. When the button is clicked, the view only changes for the top half of the screen. I will edit my post and show an image or video.

Comment: @Krish make sure to add the `NavigationView` directly inside the `body`, like: `var body: some View { NavigationView { ... } }`. Put all your other views inside it. I've added an example in my answer.